# How to deallocate memory for different vector pointer collections

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor

So I have a few vector collections below that are in different files and I'm having trouble figuring out how to deallocate them. I have my attempts below and put them all in the same destructor to reduce space, but when I run valgrind to check for memory leaks there are a BUNCH of errors and leaks detected. I was wondering if someone could confirm if I'm freeing memory for each of the collections below correctly? I'm used to working with arrays and this is my first time using vectors so I'm not quite comfortable with how they work 100%.

Vectors declared in header file:

Control class:

```
vector<docCreator*>* docs; 
vector<string>* menuOptions;
```

CreateReport class:

```
static vector<Document*> elements; 
static vector<Property<int>*> allNames
```

Destructors:

Control.cc:

```
Control::~Control(){
    for (vector<docCreator *>::iterator i = docs->begin(); i != docs->end(); ++i) {
        delete *i;
    }
    docs->clear();
    delete docs;
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < menuOptions.size(); ++i){ 
        delete menuOptions[i]; 
    }       
}
```

CreateReport.cc

```
CreateReport::~CreateReport(){
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i){ 
        delete elements[i]; 
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < allNames.size(); ++j){
        delete allNames[j]; 
    }
}
```

CreateReport is an abstract class which is why its members are static. Property is a class template.

Comment: The best way to prevent memory leaks is to make it logically impossible for them to happen, by never `new`ing and `delete`ing anything, and letting C++ containers do all that work correctly. Can you explain why any of the above pointers MUST be pointers, and -- for example -- cannot simply be `vector<docCreator> docs;`? What is the exact functional requirement for `docs` to be a pointer? All this does is improve one's chances of winning the "Pointless Use Of Pointers" award. If pointers must be used, use smart pointers instead.

Comment: The `menuOptions` is a pointer to the vector of strings. You don't need to delete each element manually.

Comment: The `elements` and `allNames` are static. Are you sure that you are deleting them from the destructor of the last instance of the `Control` class?

Comment: elements and allNames are in different classes, but for the purpose of this post I put them in the same destructor as Control. They both have their own destructors in different classes but I'm just not sure what the procedure for deleting them is as all these vectors are different types

Comment: I edited the code to help organize it. Basically elements and allNames are in an abstract class and then the other two are in the Control class

Comment: The `menuOptions` is a pointer. How can you get the sizelike that: `menuOptions.size()`?

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient information, so it is impossible to answer.   In control.cc, the releasing of (elements of) `menuOptions[i]` is incorrect.  Your compiler would have diagnosed that, since `menuOptions[i]` is of type `vector<string>` (not a pointer) so `delete menuOptions[i]` is a diagnosable error.      For the other members (or elements o members) you have provided no information on how they are initialised (e.g. in the constructor of each class)  so it is impossible to say whether you are releasing them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two errors in your code:

```cpp
for(int j = 0; j < allNames.size(); ++i)
```

You iterate using `j` but increment the `i`.

The `menuOptions` is the pointer to a vector of strings: you don't need to delete each element. That would not even compile. What you need to delete is the `menuOptions` itself:

```cpp
delete menuOptions;
```

Anyway, this code is error prone. Why not to use smart pointers? Oe even better avoid using pointers at all?